# Убрать недавно посещенные сайты из Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension, webbrowser, thumbnails

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли убрать с главной страницы Chrome миниатюры недавно посещенных сайтов? Не очистить историю! A именно убрать миниатюры, что бы была строка поиска, надпись Google и фон и больше ничего. Я знаю, есть плагины, которые делают стартовую страницу пустой, белой. Но это не совсем то.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]